# How can I make this Image fade-in-fade-out loop continuously within bxslider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bxslider

I've followed this tutorial to build a simple image fader: http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/jquery-introduction/building-a-simple-image-fader/

But for some reason mine does not loop infinitely with bxslider... after the last/third image fades, it stops. If I add one more image (a 4th), it's fine.  If I remove the bxslider call, it works.  Any ideas why?

Here's my test page:

[Image Fader Test Page](http://drupal-kwu.com/dev-templates/img-fade-demo.html)

The HTML:

```
        <ul class="rotating-images">
            <li><img src="img/girl1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img/girl2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img/girl3.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});

var fadeDuration=2000;
var displayTime=4000;
var currentIndex=1;
var nextIndex=1;
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('ul.rotating-images li').css({opacity: 0.0});
        $("'ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+nextIndex+")'").addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0},fadeDuration);
        /* setInterval("nextSlide()",displayTime);*/
        var timer = setInterval('nextSlide()',displayTime);
    });
    function nextSlide(){
        nextIndex = currentIndex+1;
        if(nextIndex> $('ul.rotating-images li').length)
        {
         nextIndex =1;
        }
        $("'ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+nextIndex+")'").addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0},fadeDuration);
        $("'ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+currentIndex+")'").animate({opacity: 0.0},fadeDuration).removeClass('show');
        currentIndex = nextIndex;
    };
```

The CSS:

```
.rotating-images{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;  
}
ul.rotating-images li {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    display:inline;
    width: 343px;
    height: 479px;
}
ul.rotating-images li.show {
    z-index:500;    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got extra quotes(') around the selector. Remove them and it will work.

change

```
$("'ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+nextIndex+")'")
$("'ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+currentIndex+")'")
```

to

```
 $("ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+nextIndex+")")
 $("ul.rotating-images li:nth-child("+currentIndex+")")
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/2/

Comment: Ah thank you! I removed the extra quotes but it still isn't looping infinitely :/ I'll update my post with a link to my test page...

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a conflict with bxslider (I have on the page linked above).